# Trigger event by mouse click VS key shortcut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I have a function that will show form dialog with JqGrid when a link is clicked.

My code is something like this:

Html:

```
<div id="mainDialog">
    <a href='#' class='showList'>Show list [Ctrl+L]</a>
    ....
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#mainDialog .showList').click(function(){
    showDialog({
        formid:"The_List",          
        path:"folder/subfolder",            
        height:820,         
        open:function(){}
    }); 
});
```

The form dialog `The_List` come from another file. And inside that file, i have something like this:

```
$("#dlgThe_List").bind('dialogopen',function(e){
    $("#listGrid").jqGrid({
        //set the grid properties
        ....
    });
});
```

Using this, it work fine where the dialog is shown with the JqGrid Table has been populated.

---

However when I trigger the `click` function above using below code, the dialog is shown but `JqGrid` Table **not even appear**:

```
$('#mainDialog').on('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 76 && e.ctrlKey){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mainDialog .showList').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

My first thought is the `showDialog` script was finished before the `jqGrid` is created.
But logically, I think there is no difference because when using shortcut key, the click function still triggered.

Is there any clarification on this?

**Edit:**
I've created [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zzq63/34/) similar with my problem, but unfortunately JqGrid is not supported.

Comment: Even `$('#mainDialog #showList')` should be `$('#mainDialog .showList')`

Comment: Sorry, it was typo. My code suppose to be `$('#mainDialog .showList')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should trigger the `dialogopen` event too:

```
$('#mainDialog').on('keydown', function(e){
   if (e.keyCode == 76 && e.ctrlKey){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#mainDialog .showList').trigger('click');
      $("#dlgThe_List").trigger('dialogopen'); //<-----trigger it too
   }
});
```

---

As you mentioned there is a typo yet you have to change your id to class of:

```
$('#mainDialog .showList')
```

which belongs to this:

```
 <a href='#' class='showList'>Show list [Ctrl+L]</a>
```

---

I have updated your fiddle and well its working here:

#### [Check the Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zzq63/35/)

its with some local data.

Comment: No luck. As  mentioned above, both of it will open the dialog, but using `Ctrl+L` key, the dialog opened without JqGrid shown up, while using mouse click, the Grid is there.

Comment: Okay! do you have reference to the jqGrid dependencies in your page.

Comment: yes, of course. if not, the jqGrid will not shown by using mouse click

Comment: nice. now both _mouse click_ and `ctrl+L` shows the grid. I believe its because the dialog come from the same file. While my actual situation is the dialog form was saved in a different file. Seems like i have to merge this two file then.